# Send Newsletter to Users at 9:00 AM in their Local Time Zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I am using the following gems:

- `timezone`
- `tzinfo`

I am trying to have a newsletter sent at `user`'s time zone, so that they get the newsletter at their 9:00:00; *not* 09:00:00 PST where my server is.

I am storing the time zones by name, like "Pacific Time (US & Canada)".  Each user has a column `user.time_zone` where their specific time zone is stored.

I have built a `job` that checks every hour for `user`s who could receive the newsletter (i.e. `user`s whose local time is 9:00 AM).

```
class NewsletterTimezoneJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.perform
      users = User.all.gets_newsletter
      users.each do |user|
      d = Date.current
      t = "09:00:00 -0700"
      t = t.to_time
      newsletter_sendtime = DateTime.new(d.year, d.month, d.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec, t.zone)
      newsletter_sendtime = newsletter_sendtime.to_s
      if user.is_in_time_around(newsletter_sendtime) 
        NewsletterMailer.send_mailer(user, newsletter_sendtime).deliver_later
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have built a method on `user` that *tries* to see if the user's local time matches `newsletter_sendtime`.

I added a +/- 5 minute window to account for slow servers.

`User.rb`:

```
def is_in_time_around(timeofday)
   timeofday = timeofday.to_time
   user_zoned =  timeofday.in_time_zone(self.time_zone)
   user_zoned = user_zoned.strftime("%r").to_time
   timeofday = timeofday.strftime("%r").to_time
   if user_zoned >= (timeofday - 5.minutes) && user_zoned <= (timeofday + 5.minutes)
    true
   end
 end
```

This `job` and `method` *should* run every hour and send to different users in different time zones each hour; and yet it currently only sends to users in "Pacific Time (US & Canada)," *each* hour and *never* sends it to any other `users.

Comment: What have you managed to do in terms of diagnosis? Is `self.time_zone` definitely correct? Why do you have the `-0700` in `t`? I'm not a Ruby person so can't do more than give a few suggestions, but it looks like you're doing a lot of string conversions, which always makes me nervous... there should be as few of those as possible.

Comment: self.time_zone does set the timezone to the user's timezone in the view.  I think the -700 is a mistake

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see a few problems with your approach: the code seems overly complex and you are most probably (as Jon noticed in his comment above) comparing only against 9AM *Pacific time*. Also, with your approach you need to traverse all users and compare the timezone of each of them - this will lead to bad performance when the users table grows.

I suggest a completely opposite approach, in plain words it's this: ***Find all timezone names in which the current local time is around 9AM now and then select users in those timezones.***

You are using Rails, everything is possible with built-in methods then. With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054039/1544012), you can get a given time (e.g. 9AM) in the given timezone (e.g. Pacific time) like this:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Pacific Time (US & Canada)"].parse("09:00:00")
# => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 09:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

The `TimeZone` module also provides the [`all` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-all) to get all defined timezones. We need to compare the local time (rounded to hours) with the desired time (9AM) in all timezones to select those zones in which the hour is currently 9AM. First let's get the local time rounded to hours:

```
Time.zone.now
# => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 13:46:25 CEST +02:00
Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.now.hour}:00:00")
# => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 13:00:00 CEST +02:00
```

Next, compare this rounded local time to 9AM in all timezones and get the matching timezone names:

```
local_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.now.hour}:00:00")
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |tz| tz.parse("09:00:00") == local_time }.map(&:name)
# => ["Greenland", "Mid-Atlantic"]
```

This particular result shows that while it is 13 hours (1PM) here in Prague, it is 9 hours (9AM) in the Greenland zone, for example.

**Having that, the rest is easy:**

```
class NewsletterTimezoneJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.perform
    User.all.gets_newsletter.with_time_zone(zones_with_local_time("09:00")).each do |user|
      NewsletterMailer.send_mailer(user).deliver_later
      # for simplicity, I removed the `newsletter_sendtime` parameter from the mailer call
    end
  end
end
```

Where the `zones_with_local_time` is a helper function defined anywhere which returns the timezones in which the local time is the given time:

```
# if defined in the NewsletterTimezoneJob, it should be a class method
def self.zones_with_local_time(hhmm)
  local_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Time.zone.now.hour}:00:00")
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.select { |tz| tz.parse("#{hhmm}:00") == local_time }.map(&:name)
end
```

And `with_time_zone` is just a scope acting upon the timezone condition in `User` model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
scope :with_time_zone,
    ->(zones) { where("time_zone in (?)", zones) }
```

Now all that you have to do is set up a cron job to run every hour e.g. the 1st minute of the hour.

Comment: This is great and it all makes sense...except I can't figure out where/how to define "zones_with_local_time(hhmm).  It keeps rejecting the "}" curly brackets and if I remove them it can't "find" the helper regardless of if I define it's inclusion.

Comment: Aha, sorry, my mistake, it should have been just a normal method. You can put it in your `NewsletterTimezoneJob` (then it would have to be a class method with `self` prefix) or in any util module you find appropriate. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: FYI I added the bounty just to reward you for your super thorough answer, not to look for others..   Thanks again.

Comment: Timezone comparison gives false when the time zone offset does not have absolute value. example UTC+5:30 gives a false result. So it never returns to such a country. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Incase if it helps someone, following might help

Schedule a job to run at 8pm (UTC) on previous day, as 8pm UTC is 9am in NewZealand and a few more timezones. And UTC 8pm is when first 9am happens for any timezone.

```
# group time_zones by utc_offset (In hours)
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.group_by { |tz| tz.utc_offset/3600.0 }.each do |utc_offset_in_hrs, time_zones|
  User.where(time_zone: time_zones).each do |user|
    # Schedule the email as per time_zone, using delayed_job's run_at param
    # Using +13, as that is the highest/first timezone to have 9AM
    NewsletterMailer.send_mailer(user).deliver_later(wait_until: 13.0 - utc_offset_in_hrs)
  end
end
```